# Spring Reactive Load Balancer Retry Is Not Working, Using RetryableLoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction

Tags: spring, spring-boot, load-balancing, spring-webclient, service-discovery

I am tring to implement the spring load balancer retry feature in my project.
I added RetryableLoadBalancerFilterExchangeFuntion (By Autowiring ) filter to the webclient builder by following this Reference: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/pull/847/commits

Without this change SCLB is working fine, the traffic was distributed to all the available instances, after adding the filter, we are facing the below errors.

> {"instant":{"epochSecond":1702552930,"nanoOfSecond":788156223},"thread":"boundedElastic-3","level":"DEBUG","loggerName":"org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.fabric8.discovery.Fabric8KubernetesDiscoveryClientUtils","message":"discovering
> endpoints in namespace :
> sampleTest","endOfBatch":false,"loggerFqcn":"org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jLog","threadId":91,"threadPriority":5,"messageTimestamp":"2023-12-14T11:22:10.788+0000"}
>
> {"instant":{"epochSecond":1702552930,"nanoOfSecond":796103469},"thread":"boundedElastic-4","level":"DEBUG","loggerName":"org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.fabric8.discovery.Fabric8KubernetesDiscoveryClientUtils","message":"filter
> not
> present","endOfBatch":false,"loggerFqcn":"org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jLog","threadId":92,"threadPriority":5,"messageTimestamp":"2023-12-14T11:22:10.796+0000"}
>
> {"instant":{"epochSecond":1702552930,"nanoOfSecond":796920350},"thread":"boundedElastic-4","level":"WARN","loggerName":"org.springframework.cloud.loadbalancer.core.RoundRobinLoadBalancer","message":"No
> servers available for service:
> 10.233.111.139","endOfBatch":false,"loggerFqcn":"org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jLog","threadId":92,"threadPriority":5,"messageTimestamp":"2023-12-14T11:22:10.796+0000"}
>
> {"instant":{"epochSecond":1702552930,"nanoOfSecond":798481135},"thread":"boundedElastic-4","level":"WARN","loggerName":"org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.reactive.RetryableLoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction","message":"LoadBalancer
> does not contain an instance for the service
> IP","endOfBatch":false,"loggerFqcn":"org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jLog","threadId":92,"threadPriority":5,"messageTimestamp":"2023-12-14T11:22:10.798+0000"}
>
> {"instant":{"epochSecond":1702552930,"nanoOfSecond":811667123},"thread":"boundedElastic-3","level":"DEBUG","loggerName":"org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.fabric8.discovery.Fabric8KubernetesDiscoveryClientUtils","message":"filter
> not
> present","endOfBatch":false,"loggerFqcn":"org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jLog","threadId":91,"threadPriority":5,"messageTimestamp":"2023-12-14T11:22:10.811+0000"}
>
> {"instant":{"epochSecond":1702552930,"nanoOfSecond":812302880},"thread":"boundedElastic-3","level":"WARN","loggerName":"org.springframework.cloud.loadbalancer.core.RoundRobinLoadBalancer","message":"No
> servers available for service:
> IP","endOfBatch":false,"loggerFqcn":"org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jLog","threadId":91,"threadPriority":5,"messageTimestamp":"2023-12-14T11:22:10.812+0000"}

NOTE: Our application is using Spring Cloud Kubernetes Discovery Server, there is no implementation of ServiceInstanceListSupplier in the code.
Reference : [https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/reference/spring-cloud-kubernetes-discoveryserver.html#:~:text=The%20Spring%20Cloud%20Discovery%20server,the%20Service%20Account%20on%20Kubernetes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/reference/spring-cloud-kubernetes-discoveryserver.html#:%7E:text=The%20Spring%20Cloud%20Discovery%20server,the%20Service%20Account%20on%20Kubernetes).

We have the following properties added in the application.properties.
spring.cloud.kubernetes.loadbalancer.mode= POD spring.cloud.loadbalancer.ribbon.enabled= false spring.cloud.loadbalancer.retry.enabled= true spring.cloud.loadbalancer.retry.retry-on-all-exceptions= true spring.cloud.loadbalancer.retry.max-retries-on-next-service-instance=2 spring.cloud.loadbalancer.retry.max-retries-on-same-service-instance=0 spring.cloud.loadbalancer.retry.retry-on-all-operations= true

Please let me know if any additional information is needed.

Thank you